# How to find maximum value of a signal in Simulink?

Tags: max, simulink, integrator

I want to use the single maximum value of a signal (with increasing values) as an input to an integrator. I have tried the max-min block but yet its not giving a single value as the maximum value. I also want ot use the maximum value of a signal as an input value to a simulink block in a single run of a model. Is it possible in with Simulink?

I have to give initial condition of an integrator as a temperature signal which is increasing from 78 to 280 degC which can again change with time. I want to input the max value (e.g.280) as an intial value to another block too. But I am not able to retrive max value from this increasing signal.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this is a Q&A site, where you post problematic code and errors and other users kindly point the issues in your code.
Please edit your post so it will show your efforts so far.

Comment: has anybody faced the same problem in simulink? Can anybody give me some cue?